# Adding "cards" to an ArrayList<Integer> in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create a game of GoFish. I'm in the process of creating the deck. I know how* to put all the number* "Cards" in an ArrayList. But since there are four different types of cards that aren't Integers (King, Queen, Jack, Ace), this causes some speedbumps.

What would be the best way to add a those four cards to this ArrayList?

```
ArrayList<Integer> cards = null;
```

Also, how would I go about making sure there are four of each card in the deck?

---

@user3189142 How to search and take the guessed card from the computer's hand and have it added to player's hand?

```
public static void playOneGame(ArrayList<Integer> cards, Scanner input)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> computer = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> person = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> computerPile = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    ArrayList<Integer> personPile = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// TODO: Deal Cards

    for (int p = 0; p < 7; p++)
    {
        person.add(cards.get(0));
        cards.remove(0);
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++)
    {
        computer.add(cards.get(0));
        cards.remove(0);
    }

// TODO: Show the person their starting hand

    System.out.println("Your cards are: " + person);

    // next line is for testing, not apart of final program
    System.out.println("Computer's cards are: " + computer);

//TODO: Play one turn with the person doing the choosing

//TODO: Let the player draw from the deck

    while (computerPile.size() + personPile.size() < 52 || !cards.isEmpty())
    {
        if (!person.isEmpty())
        {
            //TODO: Play one turn with the person doing the choosing
            System.out.println("What card do you want?");
            int card = input.nextInt();

            playPersonTurn(card, person, computer, personPile, computerPile, cards);

        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: Let the player draw from the deck
            person.add(cards.get(0));
            cards.remove(0);
        }

        showGameState(person, computerPile, personPile);

        //TODO: Play one turn with the computer doing the choosing
        if (!computer.isEmpty())
        {
            int card = computer.get((int)(Math.random()*computer.size()));  
            System.out.println("Do you have any "  + card + "'s ?");


            playComputerTurn(card, person, computer, personPile, computerPile, cards);

        }
        else if (!cards.isEmpty())
        {
            //TODO: Let the computer draw from the deck
                computer.add(cards.get(0));
                cards.remove(0);
        }

        //TODO: Create piles from hands if applicable
        checkPiles(person, personPile, computer, computerPiles);
        showGameState(person, computerPile, personPile);

    }
```

Pile Check Methods:

```
public static void checkPiles(ArrayList<Integer> person, ArrayList<Integer> personPile, ArrayList<Integer> computer, ArrayList<Integer> computerPile)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++)
        {
            if (Collections.frequency(person,i) == 4)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    personPile.add(person.remove(person.indexOf(i)));
            }
            else if (Collections.frequency(computer,i) == 4)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                {
                    computerPile.add(computer.remove(computer.indexOf(i)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Codes works well now, except when a pile is formed, it's showing all four same-number cards, like shown below with the number 1. Is there a way we can have it only show one 1?

```
What card do you want?
1
You took the computer's 1.
Here are your cards: 
2 1 13 12 12 1 6 1 6 10 9 1 
You don't have any piles yet. Computer doesn't have any piles yet. 

Do you have any 7's?
Computer went fishing. Computer drew one card from deck.
Here are your cards: 
2 13 12 12 6 6 10 9 
Here is your pile: 
1 1 1 1 
Computer doesn't have any piles yet. 

What card do you want?
```

Comment: Create a class `Card` and make all your card classes extend it. Now you can have `ArrayList<Card> cards = null`. Initialize it, and add all cards.

Comment: Loops, enums, classes. A card (class) consists of a value and a suit. These are pre-defined never changing values (enums). You need 4 of those, one for each suit (loop). This is just one of many solutions.

Comment: How come they are cards but different types? what you said does not make sense at all.

Comment: @Rp- I can't use the Card class. It has to stay as an ArrayList<Integer>.

Comment: @KickButtowski Sorry, I edited my original post. Hopefully that clears things up. I know how to add the numbered cards (2-10), but I don't know how to add the Ace, King, Queen, and Jack cards to an Integer ArrayList because they're strings.

Comment: Actually if you're interested in *blinding fast* performance you can represent the entire deck, or a partial deck, or a hand as a 64-bit integer.  But you're probably not going for that kind of performance, because Java :).  Creating a class to represent a card, with a suit and a rank is one way to go.  It's fairly common in code that works with playing cards to represent ranks as 0=> 2, 1=> 3, ... 10 => jack, 11=>queen,..., but you should probably make enums or constants to protect your sanity.

Comment: Well, define consts like `public static int TWO = 0; ... public static int JACK = 10; ...`.  But then you have to represent suits...again, it's kinda stupid to do this with integers.

Comment: @AlexCooper sounds better now. try to read about enum types or may be you need to change your logic a little bit

Comment: @Jim when we have enum type, why we go that way?

Comment: You can assign numbers to the cards of the deck, or anything else you please, using [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering). Easy.

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this, I'd add Ace as `1`, Jack as `11`, Queen as `12`, and King as `13`. Making sure there are 4 of each card in the deck is pretty easy, use nested for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 14; j++)
        cards.add(j);
}
```

That will add the 13 cards to the deck 4 times. I'm assuming you need to output the cards too, which is why you're having trouble. When outputting, you can use some simple if's to check for the Ace, King, Queen, and Jack cards, and output those names instead:

```
outputCard(int cardNumber)
{
    if (cardNumber == 1)
        System.out.println("Ace");
    else if (cardNumber == 11)
        System.out.println("Jack");
    else if (cardNumber == 12)
        System.out.println("Queen");
    else if (cardNumber == 13)
        System.out.println("King");
    else
        System.out.println(cardNumber);
}
```

To add the top 7 cards to another array list, we'll call it `hand`, try the following:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
    hand.add(cards.remove(0));
```

Then `hand` should have the 7 cards at the top of the `cards` list

To ask the computer for a card, and put it in the player's hand if the computer has it, try the following:

```
//Get the card choice from the user
int cardChoice = input.nextInt();
if (computer.contains(cardChoice))
    player.add(computer.remove(computer.indexOf(cardChoice)));
```

What this does is first check the the computer hand has at least 1 of the cards you ask for, and if it does, it finds the index of that card (`computer.indexOf`), then removes it (`computer.remove`), which returns the integer stored at that position, and adds it to the players hand `player.add`. If you need it on more than one line, let me know and I'll change it slightly.

Alright, to check if a hand has 4 of the same card, we'll use a couple for loops, like so:

```
//For the players hand
for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++)
{
    if (Collections.frequency(player,i) == 4)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            playerPile.add(player.remove(i))
        }
    }
}
```

For the computers hand, just copy-paste and change `playerPile` to `computerPile` and `player` to `computer`

The error you are getting is probably because your `pileCheck` functions have a return value, but that value isn't assigned to anything. It also probably doesn't need to be 2 functions, you should be able to merge them together:

```
public static void checkPiles()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++)
    {
        if (Collections.frequency(player,i) == 4)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                playerPile.add(player.remove(player.indexOf(i))) //Updated this
            }
        }
        else if (Collections.frequency(computer,i) == 4)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {
                computerPile.add(computer.remove(computer.indexOf(i))) //Updated this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can make the pile only show 1 of the type of card in it, by changing the loop to:

```
if (Collections.frequency(player,i) == 4)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        player.remove(player.indexOf(i));
    }
    playerPile.add(i);
}
```

Note that if you do it this way instead, you while loop will need to be changed to:

```
while (computerPile.size() + personPile.size() < 13 || !cards.isEmpty())
```

Because the total in both piles will only add to 13 instead of 52 when all the matches are found

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList of strings instead of Integers . A card deck consists of 52 playing cards, each of which has a rank and suit. For writing the createDeck() method refer to the the pseudo code below:

```
ArrayList<String> cardDeck;

enum Rank
{
    ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING;
}

enum Suit
{
    CLUB , DIAMOND , HEART , SPADE;
}

createDeck()
{
      ...... Write your logic to create a slide deck here ...........

      for(Suit aSuit : Suit.values())
          for (Rank aRank : Rank.values())
              cardDeck.add(aRank + somedelimeter + aSuit)

}
```

Comment: If you're going to the trouble of creating Suit and Rank enums, why would you want to collapse the information into a List of Strings, loosing all the information that the enums contain? Wouldn't it be better to create a Card class that held a Rank and Suit field and then use a `List<Card>` of Card? This would prevent key information loss that your recommendation causes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's because the person asking the question does not want to use a class. He insists on using ArrayList